# Xubuntu 21.10 is freezing after closing the laptop lid

Tags: xubuntu, laptop, asus

I'm using `Xubuntu 21.10` on an `ASUS ROG Zephyrus G14 GA401QM-K2030T` laptop. When I close the laptop lid the desktop freezes. Could someone help resolve this issue?

**Afterwords:**

It seems that the problem appears not only when I close the lid, but also if the computer stays idle for some time.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi 40 GB